# Example for number of predictors increasing with sample size

Tags: high-dimensional

High-dimensional literature typically assumes that the number of predictors $p$ increases with sample size $n$, say $p = O(\exp n)$. I can understand that assuming $n\to\infty$ corresponds to increasing the number of observations in a study, say we collect more samples. Are there any actual examples of $p$ increasing with $n$?

Comment: "semi-parametric" is a good search keyword.

Comment: Imaging and such..